# Linux Rider new solution only empty solution

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jetbrains-ide, rider

When opening Rider from the desktop short cut I only have empty solution when creating a new solution.

When running Rider using `sudo ./rider.sh` I can see all the solutions I can create.

I tried modifying the `.desktop` file to run it with pkexec and that didn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 18 so there's no gksudo.

[image: no sudo]

[image: using sudo]

Comment: Could you open Rider from desktop, create an empty solution and browse logs?

Comment: Help -> Show logs in... -> backend.log

Comment: Probably you have to send all logs to us, e.g. via an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER